# Interpolate whole arrays of complex numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers, interpolation

I have a number of 2-dimensional np.arrays (all of equal size) containing complex numbers. Each of them belongs to one position in a 4-dimensional space. Those positions are sparse and distributed irregularly (a latin hypercube to be precise).
I would like to interpolate this data to other points in the same 4-dimensional space.

I can successfully do this for simple numbers, using either `sklearn.kriging()`, `scipy.interpolate.Rbf()` (or others):

```
# arrayof co-ordinates: 2 4D sets
X = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],\
              [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

# two numbers, one for each of the points above 
Y = np.array([1,\
              0])

# define the type of gaussian process I want
kriging = gp.GaussianProcess(theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=4.0,\
            corr='linear', normalize=True, nugget=0.00001, optimizer='fmin_cobyla')

# train the model on the data
kmodel = kriging.fit(X,Y)

# interpolate
kmodel.predict(np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0]))
# returns: array([ 0.5])
```

If I try to use arrays (or just complex numbers) as data, this doesn't work:

```
# two arrays of complex numbers, instead of the numbers 
Y = np.array([[1+1j, -1-1j],\
              [0+0j,  0+0j]])

kmodel = kriging.fit(X,Y)
# returns: ValueError: The number of features in X (X.shape[1] = 1) should match the sample size used for fit() which is 4.
```

This is obvious since the docstring for `kriging.fit()` clearly states that it needs an array of n scalars, one per each element in the first dimension of X.

One solution is to decompose the arrays in Y into individual numbers, those into real and imaginary parts, make a separate interpolation of each of those and then put them together again. I can do this with the right combination of loops and some artistry but it would be nice if there was a method (e.g. in `scipy.interpolate`) that could handle an entire np.array instead of scalar values.

I'm not fixed on a specific algorithm (yet), so I'd be happy to know about any that can use arrays of complex numbers as the "variable" to be interpolated. Since -- as I said -- there are few and irregular points in space (and no grid to interpolate on), simple linear interpolation won't do, of course.

Comment: be precise. what does it mean that it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @flebool as I understand, he wants to know if it makes sense to decompose complex numbers into imaginary and real parts, interpolate them separately (converting imaginary to real and back, possibly), and composing the result back into complex. Would it be that?

Comment: Very much that, yes. The interpolation functions known to me can only handle skalars, and I'd like to know if there's something that does complex numbers and matrices (and ideally matrices of complex numbers) as well.

Comment: +1, I just have a similar problem, 2D interpolation, and the Y data is a dict containing several quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working around the problem, but after learning a good deal more about response surfaces and the like, I now understand that this is a far-from-trivial problem. I could not have expected a simple solution in `numpy`, and the question would have probably been better placed in a forum on mathematics than on programming.

If I had to tackle such a task again, I'd probably use `scikit-learn` to try and establish either a co-Kriging interpolation for both components, or two separate Kriging (or more general, Gaussian Process) models which share a common set of model constants, optimized to minimize the combined error amplitude, (i.e.: Full model error square is the sum of both partial model errors)

-- but first I'd go and have a look if there aren't any useful papers on the topic already.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways of looking at complex numbers:

1. Cartesian Form ( a + bi ) and
2. Polar/Euler Form ( A * exp(i * phi) )

When you say you want to interpolate between two polar coordinates, do you want to interpolate with respect to the real/imaginary components (1), or with respect to the number's magnitude and phase (2)?

You CAN break things down into real and imaginary components,

```
X = 2 * 5j
X_real = np.real(X)
X_imag = np.imag(X)

# Interpolate the X_real and X_imag

# Reconstruct X
X2 = X_real + 1j * X_imag
```

However, With real-life applications that involve complex numbers, such as digital filter design, you quite often want to work with numbers in Polar/exponential form.

Therefore instead of interpolating the np.real() and np.imag() components, you may want to break it down into magnitude & phase using np.abs() and [Angle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html) or [Arctan2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#numpy.arctan2), and interpolate separately. You might do this, for example, when trying to interpolate the Fourier Transform of a digital filter.

```
Y = 1+2j
mag = np.abs(Y)
phase = np.angle(Y)
```

The interpolated values can be converted back into complex (Cartesian) numbers using the Eulers formula

```
# Complex number
y = mag * np.exp( 1j * phase)

# Or if you want the real and imaginary complex components separately,
realPart, imagPart = mag * np.cos(phase) , mag * np.sin(phase)
```

Depending on what you're doing, this gives you some real flexibility with the interpolation methods you use.

Comment: Not being familiar with `numpy` I could be way off base here, but wouldn't you cause problems by interpolating the phase data directly?  For example, if two adjacent pixels were `-pi + 0.1` and `pi - 0.3`, you would *want* to get `pi - 0.1`, but would actually get `-0.1`.  Or does the interpolation function know how to properly interpolate phase?

Comment: I had to think about that question for a minute. I think what you're saying is like: If you had close-together data whose phase was increasing up to 2pi and crossed over, arctan2() would warp the phase back down to 0 when you wanted it to continue up past 2pi for the sake of interpolation. [Numpy.unwrap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) would be what you want to correct for this.

Comment: Exactly what I was getting at, yes.  Cool that `Numpy` has a built-in to deal with it.  :-)  Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly been a while but I thought I should remark on why I did not choose this as a solution. Decomposing by amplitude/phase will give me an interpolation better suited for some purposes, but it's still two independent interpolation models. If the input data has some correlation between amplitude and phase (or real/imaginary, for that part), this will not necessarily be caught by the interpolation models, so interpolation errors for both of them will be independent.