# Scipy zoom with complex values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, complex-numbers, zooming

I have a numpy array of values and I wanted to scale (zoom) it. With floats I was able to use `scipy.ndimage.zoom` but now my array contains complex values which are not supported by `scipy.ndimage.zoom`. My workaround was to separate the array into two parts (real and imaginary) and scale them independently. After that I add them back together. Unfortunately this produces a lot of tiny artifacts in my 'image'. Does somebody know a better way? Maybe there also exists a python library for this? I couldn't find one.

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to interpolate between the complex numbers when you `zoom`.  This answer might give some hints as to why that's difficult: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918036/interpolate-whole-arrays-of-complex-numbers .  This open issue would suggest that it's not resolved within scipy https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2650

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good answer but it seems to work quite well. Instead of using the default parameters for the zoom method, I'm using `order=0`. I then proceed to deal with the real and imaginary part separately, as described in my question. This seems to reduce the artifacts although some smaller artifacts remain. It is by no means perfect and if somebody has a better answer, I would be very interested.