# How to reduce the size of array with complex values

Tags: python, arrays, image-resizing, complex-numbers

I have an image that is represented by an array of complex values. I would like to reduce the size of this image. But I don't know how.
I give you an example:

Let's say that I have an array of 3x3:

```py
a = [[1+2j , 3+4j , 5+6j],
     [1+2j , 3+4j , 5+6j],
     [1+2j , 3+4j , 5+6j]]
```

I would like to have my image sized 2x2. How can I do that with Python?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I thought about using imresize from scipy. But the input array can't be complex

Comment: I've not seen an "image" with complex numbers before, what do the imaginary parts represent?  maybe as a result of a 2d fourier transform, or something?  at which point it's not really an "image" any more…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolate whole arrays of complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918036/interpolate-whole-arrays-of-complex-numbers)